# Getting warning when forgiving null through Nulllable.Value property on value type

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've tried to reproduce a null-forgiving code applied to a value type, but it does not generate any warning: [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6857RA). In actual code, I'm getting a warning. I'm actually compiling with .NET Core 6.0.

I'm getting multiple compile-time warnings on a code base, some of them related to null-forgiving code. I'm trying to use either `SomeNullableValue.Value` or `SomeNullableValue!`, but the compiler complains I'm possibly passing `null` argument to a function in both ways.

The case I'm dealing with now is an `enum` that is initially null, but is assigned later in the same control flow; in this case, it is `Ast.ContStmtTarget? t`, where `Ast.ContStmtTarget` is an `enum`:

```
NextToken();
Ast.ContStmtTarget? t = null;
if (CurrentToken.Type == Token.Keyword) {
    switch (CurrentToken.StringValue) {
        case "do": t = Ast.ContStmtTarget.Do; break;
        case "for": t = Ast.ContStmtTarget.For; break;
        case "loop": t = Ast.ContStmtTarget.Loop; break;
        case "while": t = Ast.ContStmtTarget.While; break;
    }
}
if (!t.HasValue) {
    FatalError(0x80A0400, GetTokenSpan());
}
r = new Ast.ContStmt(t.Value);
```

The compiler is outputting warning in the last line, `r = ...;`, with the column pointing to `t.Value`. Also, the `Ast.ContStmt` constructor takes a non-nullable value (the `enum`).

```
...\Parser.cs(1410,38): warning CS8629: Nullable value type may be null.
```

I've put compilable project on GitHub (`dotnet build`):

- [`Parser`](https://github.com/shockbasic/sb/blob/4631605f6a7b90ef6edfc8a3fbbd3874f4a7e061/src/ShockBasic.Syntax/Parser.cs#L1410)
- [`Ast.ContStmt`](https://github.com/shockbasic/sb/blob/4631605f6a7b90ef6edfc8a3fbbd3874f4a7e061/src/ShockBasic.Syntax/Ast.cs#L1102)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compiler is warning you that you can reach that line with t == null. Does FatalError return? I assume it throws but the compiler doesnt know that

do

```
if (!t.HasValue) {
    FatalError(0x80A0400, GetTokenSpan());
} else{
   r = new Ast.ContStmt(t.Value);
}
```

Comment: Correct, it throws, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can mark `FatalError` with [`DoesNotReturnAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) to help compiler determine that code after `if` is unreachable in case `!t.HasValue` otherwise compiler can't verify that code will not actually be called:

```
[DoesNotReturn]
private void FatalError(int msgId, Span? span, Dictionary<string, object>? vars = null) {
    throw new SyntaxException(Program.Collect(new Problem(msgId, false, vars, span.Value)));
}
```